# KnpPaginatorBundle sorting a Doctrine ArrayCollection

Tags: sorting, symfony, twig, knppaginator

Let's say I have an entity A with columns ID, foo, and bar which are either strings, integers or DateTime objects. This entity has all of the standard getters like getId(), getFoo(), and getBar().

In my controller, I have an object that is of another entity called B. The relationship between B and A is one to many. The getAllA() function finds all A associated with B which will return a Doctrine ArrayCollection. So with the object in the controller, I invoke

```
$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$paginatedObject = $paginator->paginate(
            $object->getAllA(),
            $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),
            3
```

Now pagination works fine, but how do I sort? In the table header row I have

```
{{ knp_pagination_sortable(paginatedObject, 'ID', '???????????????') }}
```

but what goes in for the question marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a DQL query like

```
'SELECT o FROM AcmeBundle:Object o'
```

and then the third parameter would be 'o.id'

[source](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle#controller)

Comment: I don't really like this solution since it involves me writing more code, but at least it works. Someone should update the documentation and say sorting does NOT work on array/ArrayCollection